# What is the derivative of the following functional?

Tags: derivatives, gateaux-derivative

How can we find the derivative of the following functional w.r.t the function $\lambda$:

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{J}(\lambda) = \int_0^1 \left(  \int_t^1 \lambda(s) ds \right)dt
\end{equation*}

where $\lambda \in L_2[0,1]$.

I guess we should apply Gateaux differential:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{1}{\alpha} \mathcal{J}(\lambda +\alpha h) - \mathcal{J}(\lambda)
\end{equation*}

with $h\in L_2$ being arbitrary. or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional $\mathcal{J}$ is linear hence $\mathcal{J}'=\mathcal{J} .$

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate? I do not see what you mean.

Comment: If $\mathcal J$ is linear, what does $\frac 1\alpha(\mathcal J(\lambda + \alpha h) - \mathcal J(\lambda))$ equal to?

Comment: The calculation that I got is that the differential is $\mathcal{J}(h)$. But since $h$ should be arbitrary, I do not see how can this be right

Comment: I think you are talking about directional derivative. The directional derivative in the direction $h$ is equal to $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{J}}{\partial h} =\mathcal{J} (h)$$

Comment: I think you should reread [definitions from multivariable calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Directional_derivatives) to convince yourself this is alright. Frechet derivative generalizes differential of multivariable function, and Gateaux derivative generalizes partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks. Acually I'm trying to look at this, because I'm trying to maximize a functional (Lagrangian): See my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266557/how-can-we-maximize-the-following-functional So far, I did not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y$ are normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator then $T' =T. $ This follows immadietely from equality $$\frac{||T(x+h)-T(x)-T(h)||}{||h||} =0$$

Comment: The differential as I know it should be an element of $Y$.

Comment: This is Frechet derivative (the differential as you know from multivariable calculus) which implies Gateaux derivative. And how exactly is differential element of $Y$? Differential is linear operator that is the best approximation of a function.

Comment: The derivative of $\mathcal{J}$ is a linear operator yes. However the differential at an element in $X$ is an element of $Y$